# Scaling data into range 0 to 1

Tags: normalization, scaling, stat

I'd like to scale the data into the range 0 to 1. However, normalization gives result that min value is 0 and max valu is 1 which is not work for my data. I want a range 0 to 1 in in which after scaling my min data is not 0 (It should be 0.00XX) and max data should be like 0.9xx . Any ideas for this case?

Comment: A hack on set `A` would be to insert dummy variables `A_{min}-εσ`, `A_{max}+εσ`, where `ε` is user-defined, and `σ^2` is the variance, do the normalisation, and then delete them?

Answer (score 0):

If one has access to the scale parameters of the linear transformation, scale to *[x<sub>min</sub>, x<sub>max</sub>] -> [0.00XX, 0.9XX]* instead of *[0, 1]*. Alternately, for the data *x ∈ A*, you could insert temporary points on either side, *[x<sub>-</sub>, x<sub>+</sub>]* so that *∀ x ∈ A, x<sub>-</sub> < x < x<sub>+</sub>*; again scale the points to *[0, 1]*. This will make *x<sub>-</sub>' = 0, x<sub>+</sub>' = 1*, then delete those points.

One might want to automate this if one is doing it a lot; I suspect that machine learning might have an appropriate algorithm. Maybe a simple solution using the standard deviation, *σ*, of *A*, is to make *x<sub>-</sub> = x<sub>min</sub> - ασ, x<sub>+</sub> = x<sub>max</sub> + ασ*, where *α* is proportional to the length of the separation from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tough about scaling it between the values you can accept?

Like *0.0001* till *0.9999*?

Or you could add the 2 boundaries for your data that are larger then your dataset range:

If you data is between *2 and 14*, manualy define it as *1 and 15* and scale the data between it.

Or "manualy" define it automaticaly with some *percentage* of your *MAX* and *MIN* values.